# Highschool thermal expansion problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

I'm preparing for a test, and have stumbled on a problem I have no idea how to solve.
It goes like that: "Two metal rods, from the same metal have lengths 1.001m and 1.002m at 20 degrees celsius. If we cool the second one down and heat the first one for the same temperature difference, they have the same length. What is that temperature distance.

The answer should be -5 degrees for long one and 45 degrees for the hot one. Or the temperature change of 25 degrees. But, I find it illogical, since how much heat we would need is dependent on the alpha constant for that metal. Also trying to solve it by setting the lengths plus change equal and getting out the temperature change isn't possible as alphas don't cancel.
Is it unsolvable, or what am I missing? If you need to go college level I'm happy to learn.

Comment: If by "alpha" you mean the coefficient of thermal expansion, then since it is stated that the two metals are made of the same metal, alpha will be the same for both.

Comment: Yes, the problem is unsolvable without being given the thermal expansion coefficient. Check that you didn't miss part of the problem where the metal was identified or $\alpha$ specified as $2\times 10^{-5}\, \mathrm{K}^{-1}$, for example.

Comment: It's missing, so it's impossible, right?

Comment: Metals near 20°C can have thermal expansion coefficients that are positive, negative, or approximately zero. You can see how this would completely change the range of potential answers, given no additional information.

Comment: @Chemomechanics:  Now I'm curious:  what are some metals with negative thermal expansion coefficients near 20°C?  I was always under the impression that such materials were pretty rare, and that most common metals have a positive expansion coefficient.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert [example](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/11310/1131013/Negative-thermal-expansion-ALLVAR-Alloys-for-smaller-optics/10.1117/12.2546869.short)

Comment: The answer you cite doesn't match the problem statement.  As an example, the shorter rod should be heated by 25 deg C and the long rod should be cooled by 25 deg C, as the problem stated that the temperature difference was the same for both rods.